# local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, laravel, access-denied

I have a problem with Laravel, and the error is in the title.

MySQL is configured to not have a "root" password.

On the same machine Joomla is installed with the exact same configuration data, so it should not be a MySQL error.

I've:

- deleted .env file;
- cleaned the cache.

Comment: why did you deleted env? check your password in the env

Comment: You should not delete the .env file. It contains the configurations for your app. Restore the file and configure the cache again. `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Is env file necessary just for develop environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can download env.example, rename it to .env, and edit it. Just set up correct database credentials, etc.

Don't forget to run thee `php artisan key:generate` command which will generate an application key and add it to the .env file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your host URL.

```
 'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database',
```

Maybe it's different from 'localhost'. Like 192.168.0.1.